# GradientDrawable in Code

Tags: android

I can use the following XML just fine

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns...">
     <gradient
         android:startColor="#255779"
         android:centerColor="#3e7492"
         android:endColor="#a6c0cd"
         android:angle="90"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#0d202e"/>
</shape>
```

the gradient come up nicely

i am trying to do the same thing just using code (no XMLs)

```
int colors[] = { 0xff255779 , 0xff3e7492, 0xffa6c0cd };

GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);

setBackgroundDrawable(g);
```

The gradient DOES come up but its not the same as the one the one from XML, i mean the colors are same but gradient is not same, i think it has to do with the start,middle,end colors in the xml

also how do i add a stroke

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#gradient-element)

> **android:angle**
>   Integer. The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, **90 is bottom to top**. It must be a multiple of 45. Default is 0

but you are using GradientDrawable.Orientation.**TOP_BOTTOM** in your code. That's why gradient directions are different

You should use GradientDrawable.Orientation.**BOTTOM_TOP** instead.