# unable to set Angle for radial-gradient nativeScript(Android) programmatically

Tags: nativescript

I need to access to the [`android:angle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:angle) property.

```
backgroundDrawable = new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
        backgroundDrawable.setColors(_colors);
        backgroundDrawable.setGradientType(RADIAL_GRADIENT);
        backgroundDrawable.setGradientRadius(100.0);
        backgroundDrawable.setGradientAngle(270); // Getting Error at this line. Works fine if i remove this.
        backgroundDrawable.setGradientCenter(0.50, 0.50);
        nativeView.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

I have even tried `backgroundDrawable.setAngle(270)`, but it doesn't help. How do I access it?

Comment: I don't see .setGradientAngle() listed in the docs for GradientDrawable. Where did you find that method, what API version?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: @BradMartin I was just trying to give an angle as i want to achieve radial Gradient. I didn't knew that there is no method. Do u have any reference for radialGradient?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call a method (*setGradientAngle()*) that does not exist in the GradientDrawable class. As you mentioned you want to set the **android:angle** from the code but that is not possible neither in NativeScript or the native Java code of Android because there is no setter publicly exposed from the android "library". Setting an xml attribute from a library which does not expose a setter for that property is not possible without reflections. You can read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2rmtgm/set_xml_attributes_programmatically_if_no_setter/) thread that goes through a similar scenario.

After some digging around I found that you could set the **GradientDrawable.Orientation** to for example **BOTTOM_TOP** which should be equal to *setGradientAngle(90)*. There are [multiple values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.Orientation.html) for the Orientation enumeration that you could experiment with. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177401/gradientdrawable-in-code) is a different thread that shows the explained approach.